# How to count a column based on the same id in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
id_td || id_tr || cost || qty || subcost ||
-------------------------------------------
td01  || tr02  || 100  ||  2  ||  200    ||
td02  || tr02  || 200  ||  3  ||  600    ||
td03  || tr03  || 400  ||  1  ||  400    ||
```

How can I calculate the `subcost` column filtered by only having an `id_tr` value of `tr02`?

Comment: You need to write a query.  What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what your question is...  can you show your expected result?

Comment: The question isn't clear, at least to me. Can you share the result you're trying to get for this sample data?

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for the Query it would be:

```
SELECT SUM(subcost) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE id_tr = 'tr02';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select id_tr
      ,subcost=sum(subcost)
 From  YourTableName
 Where id_tr='tr02'
Group by id_tr
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT SUM(subcost) AS Sum_subcost 
FROM table_name 
WHERE id_tr = 'tr02'
```